# Retrieve Local variable name from PDB files

Tags: c#, .net, cil

i'm currently trying to retrieve source code from IL bytecodes and PDB files,
i'm arrived to the point where i can generate source code from IL and reflection
i know the name of local variable names is included in the pdb file.
My question is how can i find it back ? what libs should i use to handle the pdb files (if any) or should i write the code myself ? where can i find information about pdb file format ?
currently in the generated sourcecode i'm using auto generated values for local variables but i want to change that as i believe it is possible to find that information back if you have pdb files at your disposal.
I tried to look on google but i didnt find any usefull informations.

Thanks in advance for you replies ;)

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to read local variable names from a MethodInfo using the types in `System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore`:

```
public class LocalVariableNameReader
{
    Dictionary<int, string> _names = new Dictionary<int, string> ();

    public string this [int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!_names.ContainsKey (index)) return null;
            return _names [index];
        }
    }

    public LocalVariableNameReader (MethodInfo m)
    {
        ISymbolReader symReader = SymUtil.GetSymbolReaderForFile (m.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location, null);
        ISymbolMethod met = symReader.GetMethod (new SymbolToken (m.MetadataToken));
        VisitLocals (met.RootScope);
    }

    void VisitLocals (ISymbolScope iSymbolScope)
    {
        foreach (var s in iSymbolScope.GetLocals ()) _names [s.AddressField1] = s.Name;
        foreach (var c in iSymbolScope.GetChildren ()) VisitLocals (c);
    }
}
```

The `SymUtil` class comes from [this example](http://sorin.serbans.net/blog/index.php/2010/08/10/how-to-read-pdb-files/).

**Edit**: The above link is broken. From a google cache:

> A long time ago I was looking on how to process pdb files in order to
>   get additional information that reflection simply could not provide.
>   Now I stumped over a 5 year old post of Mike Stall
>   ([here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/08/25/sample-pdb2xml.aspx))
>   and suddenly all became clear. I’ve put together a small example which
>   uses .net 4.0 to read the method body code as it is in the source code
>   from where the assembly was compiled. Mind you that in order for this
>   to work you have to have the pdb of the assembly available. Also
>   please make sure you add a refference to ISymWrapper and your project
>   is targeting .Net 4.0 framework, not .Net 4.0 Client.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace PdbTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly ass = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            ISymbolReader symreader = SymUtil.GetSymbolReaderForFile(ass.Location, null);

            MethodInfo m = ass.GetType("PdbTest.TestClass").GetMethod("GetStringRepresentation");
            ISymbolMethod met = symreader.GetMethod(new SymbolToken(m.MetadataToken));

            int count = met.SequencePointCount;

            ISymbolDocument[] docs = new ISymbolDocument[count];
            int[] offsets = new int[count];
            int[] lines = new int[count];
            int[] columns = new int[count];
            int[] endlines = new int[count];
            int[] endcolumns = new int[count];

            met.GetSequencePoints(offsets, docs, lines, columns, endlines, endcolumns);

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(docs[0].URL);
            string[] linesOfCode = reader.ReadToEnd().Split('n');
            reader.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("The content of method PdbTest.TestClass.GetStringRepresentation");
            for (int i = lines[0]; i < endlines[count - 1] - 1; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(linesOfCode[i]);
            }
        }
    }


    #region test class

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        Apples,
        Oranges
    }

    public partial class TestClass
    {
        public string GetStringRepresentation(MyEnum e)
        {
            MyEnum e2 = MyEnum.Apples;
            return e.ToString() + e2.ToString();
        }
    }

    #endregion test class

    #region Get a symbol reader for the given module

    // Encapsulate a set of helper classes to get a symbol reader from a file.
    // The symbol interfaces require an unmanaged metadata interface.
    static class SymUtil
    {
        static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
            public static extern int CoCreateInstance(
                [In] ref Guid rclsid,
                [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] Object pUnkOuter,
                [In] uint dwClsContext,
                [In] ref Guid riid,
                [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out Object ppv);
        }

        // Wrapper.
        public static ISymbolReader GetSymbolReaderForFile(string pathModule, string searchPath)
        {
            return SymUtil.GetSymbolReaderForFile(
                new System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore.SymBinder(), pathModule, searchPath);
        }

        // We demand Unmanaged code permissions because we're reading from the file 
        // system and calling out to the Symbol Reader
        // @TODO - make this more specific.
        [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(
            System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand,
            Flags = System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)]
        public static ISymbolReader GetSymbolReaderForFile(
           System.Diagnostics.SymbolStore.SymBinder binder, string pathModule, string searchPath)
        {
            // Guids for imported metadata interfaces.
            Guid dispenserClassID = new Guid(0xe5cb7a31, 0x7512, 0x11d2, 0x89, 
                0xce, 0x00, 0x80, 0xc7, 0x92, 0xe5, 0xd8); // CLSID_CorMetaDataDispenser
            Guid dispenserIID = new Guid(0x809c652e, 0x7396, 0x11d2, 0x97, 0x71, 
                0x00, 0xa0, 0xc9, 0xb4, 0xd5, 0x0c); // IID_IMetaDataDispenser
            Guid importerIID = new Guid(0x7dac8207, 0xd3ae, 0x4c75, 0x9b, 0x67, 
                0x92, 0x80, 0x1a, 0x49, 0x7d, 0x44); // IID_IMetaDataImport

            // First create the Metadata dispenser.
            object objDispenser;
            NativeMethods.CoCreateInstance(ref dispenserClassID, null, 1, 
                ref dispenserIID, out objDispenser);

            // Now open an Importer on the given filename. We'll end up passing this importer 
            // straight through to the Binder.
            object objImporter;
            IMetaDataDispenser dispenser = (IMetaDataDispenser)objDispenser;
            dispenser.OpenScope(pathModule, 0, ref importerIID, out objImporter);

            IntPtr importerPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            ISymbolReader reader;
            try
            {
                // This will manually AddRef the underlying object, so we need to 
                // be very careful to Release it.
                importerPtr = Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject(objImporter, 
                    typeof(IMetadataImport));

                reader = binder.GetReader(importerPtr, pathModule, searchPath);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (importerPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.Release(importerPtr);
                }
            }
            return reader;
        }
    }
    #region Metadata Imports

    // We can use reflection-only load context to use reflection to query for 
    // metadata information rather
    // than painfully import the com-classic metadata interfaces.
    [Guid("809c652e-7396-11d2-9771-00a0c9b4d50c"), 
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    interface IMetaDataDispenser
    {
        // We need to be able to call OpenScope, which is the 2nd vtable slot.
        // Thus we need this one placeholder here to occupy the first slot..
        void DefineScope_Placeholder();

        //STDMETHOD(OpenScope)(                   // Return code.
        //LPCWSTR     szScope,                // [in] The scope to open.
        //  DWORD       dwOpenFlags,            // [in] Open mode flags.
        //  REFIID      riid,                   // [in] The interface desired.
        //  IUnknown    **ppIUnk) PURE;         // [out] Return interface on success.
        void OpenScope([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String szScope, 
            [In] Int32 dwOpenFlags, [In] ref Guid riid, 
            [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out Object punk);

        // Don't need any other methods.
    }

    // Since we're just blindly passing this interface through managed code to the Symbinder, 
    // we don't care about actually importing the specific methods.
    // This needs to be public so that we can call Marshal.GetComInterfaceForObject() on 
    // it to get the underlying metadata pointer.
    [Guid("7DAC8207-D3AE-4c75-9B67-92801A497D44"), 
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [CLSCompliant(true)]
    public interface IMetadataImport
    {
        // Just need a single placeholder method so that it doesn't complain
        // about an empty interface.
        void Placeholder();
    }
    #endregion

    #endregion Get a symbol reader for the given module
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the question was asked in **2011**. Now it's **2019** and there are 2 options to retrieve local variabls from a method.

First let's define `VariableInfo` to keep local variable parameters:

```
public class VariableInfo : IEquatable<VariableInfo>
{
    public int Index { get; }
    public string Name { get; }
    public Type Type { get; }

    public VariableInfo(int index, Type type, string name) =>
        (Index, Type, Name) = (index, type, name);

    public override bool Equals(object obj) =>
        Equals(obj as VariableInfo);

    public bool Equals(VariableInfo info) =>
        info != null &&
        Index.Equals(info.Index) &&
        Name.Equals(info.Name) &&
        Type.Equals(info.Type);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hash = 17;
            hash = 23 * hash + Index.GetHashCode();
            hash = 23 * hash + Name.GetHashCode();
            hash = 23 * hash + Type.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"Index {Index}, Type {Type}, Name {Name}";
}
```

Then let's define `ILocalsReader` interface as folows:

```
public interface ILocalsReader
{
    VariableInfo[] Read(MethodBase info);
}
```

Now one can implement it with [`Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorApi`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorApi) like this:

```
public class MicrosoftDebuggingReader : ILocalsReader
{
    public VariableInfo[] Read(MethodBase info)
    {
        var il = info.GetMethodBody().LocalVariables.ToArray();

        return SymbolAccess
            .GetReaderForFile(info.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location)
            .GetMethod(new SymbolToken(info.MetadataToken))
            .RootScope
            .GetInnerScopesRecursive()
            .SelectMany(scope => scope.GetLocals())
            .Select(local =>
                new VariableInfo(local.AddressField1,
                                 il[local.AddressField1].LocalType,
                                 local.Name))
           .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Where `GetInnerScopesRecursive` is an extension method:

```
internal static class SymbolScopeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ISymbolScope> GetInnerScopesRecursive(this ISymbolScope scope)
    {
        yield return scope;
        foreach (var innerScope in scope.GetChildren()
            .SelectMany(innerScope => innerScope.GetInnerScopesRecursive()))
            yield return innerScope;
    }
}
```

**Remember to build against `x64`.**

Another option is using [`Mono.Cecil`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Cecil) like this:

```
public class MonoCecilReader : ILocalsReader
{
    public VariableInfo[] Read(MethodBase info)
    {
        var method = info.GetMethodDefinition();
        method.Module.ReadSymbols();

        var pdb = Path.ChangeExtension(info.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location, "pdb");
        new PdbReaderProvider().GetSymbolReader(method.Module, pdb)
                               .Read(method);

        var il = info.GetMethodBody().LocalVariables;
        return Read(method, il);
    }

    public VariableInfo[] Read(MethodDefinition method, IList<LocalVariableInfo> il)
    {
        return method
               .DebugInformation
               .Scope
               .GetInnerScopesRecursive()
               .SelectMany(scope => scope.Variables)
               .Select(local =>
                   new VariableInfo(local.Index,
                                    il[local.Index].LocalType,
                                    local.Name))
               .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Where `GetMethodDefinition` is an extension method:

```
public static class MethodDefinitionExtensions
{
    public static MethodDefinition GetMethodDefinition(this MethodBase info) =>
        AssemblyDefinition
        .ReadAssembly(info.DeclaringType.Assembly.Location)
        .Modules
        .SelectMany(module => module.GetTypes())
        .Single(type => type.FullNameMatches(info.DeclaringType))
        .Methods
        .FirstOrDefault(method =>
            method.Name.Equals(info.Name) &&
            method.ReturnType.FullName.Equals(info.GetReturnType().FullName) &&
            method.Parameters.Select(parameter => parameter.ParameterType.FullName)
                  .SequenceEqual(info.GetParameters().Select(parameter => parameter.ParameterType.FullName)));
}
```

And `GetReturnType` is an extension method:

```
public static class MethodBaseExtensions
{
    public static Type GetReturnType(this MethodBase method)
    {
        if (method is MethodInfo info)
            return info.ReturnType;

        if (method is ConstructorInfo ctor)
            return typeof(void);

        throw new ArgumentException($"Argument {nameof(method)} has unsupported type {method.GetType()}.");
    }
}
```

And `FullNameMatches` is an extension method:

```
internal static class TypeDefinitionExtensions
{
    public static bool FullNameMatches(this TypeDefinition typeDefinition, Type type) =>
        typeDefinition.FullName.Replace("/", "").Equals(type.FullName.Replace("+", ""));
}
```

And `GetInnerScopesRecursive` is an extension method:

```
internal static class ScopeDebugInformationExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<ScopeDebugInformation> GetInnerScopesRecursive(this ScopeDebugInformation scope)
    {
        yield return scope;
        foreach (var innerScope in scope.Scopes
            .SelectMany(innerScope => innerScope.GetInnerScopesRecursive()))
            yield return innerScope;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var info = new Action<string>(Foo).GetMethodInfo();

        Console.WriteLine("\tMicrosoft.Samples.Debugging.CorSymbolStore");
        foreach (var v in new MicrosoftDebuggingReader().Read(info))
            Console.WriteLine(v);

        Console.WriteLine("\tMono.Cecil");
        foreach (var v in new MonoCecilReader().Read(info))
            Console.WriteLine(v);
    }

    public static void Foo(string s)
    {
        for (int i; ;)
            for (double j; ;)
                for (bool k; ;)
                    for (object m = 0; ;)
                        for (DateTime n; ;) { }
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
        Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorSymbolStore
Index 0, Type System.Int32, Name i
Index 1, Type System.Double, Name j
Index 2, Type System.Boolean, Name k
Index 3, Type System.Object, Name m
Index 4, Type System.DateTime, Name n
        Mono.Cecil
Index 0, Type System.Int32, Name i
Index 1, Type System.Double, Name j
Index 2, Type System.Boolean, Name k
Index 3, Type System.Object, Name m
Index 4, Type System.DateTime, Name n
```

**Note:**

- `Microsoft.Samples.Debugging.CorApi` has ~9k downloads and was last updated on 10.12.2011
- `Mono.Cecil` has ~3415k downloads and latest commit on 05.08.2019

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [CCI](http://ccimetadata.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex. It has a PDBReader project.