# Compare variable name to a string

Tags: c#, string, stringbuilder, string.format

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and C#

I want to be able to compare the name of a string variable with a string I create.

The string variable is called print1 (for instance)

```
public string print1;
```

I then create a string to like so:

```
foreach (int number in orderOfNumber)
{
    string printNumber = String.Format("print{0}", number-1);
}
```

I discard this if 'number' = 1 so I am not concerned with the number ever being 0

What I would like to do is print a string in a MessageBox with a few lines.
One line will have the time taken between clicking two pictures on the screen.
Basically formatted like this:

//Time taken:

1 and 2 -> 1.234 secs

What I have so far is this:

```
orderBuilder.Append(String.Format("{0} and {1}\t\t", orderOfNumber[number-1], orderOfPicturesNumber[number])).Append("" + printNumber + "\n");
```

No matter how I try I always end up with

1 and 2      print1

This is close to what I want as the value for print1 is actually 1.234

Is there a way to replace the 'string' print1 with the original variable print1?

Comment: Explain the original task. What you're trying to do looks like a terrible design decision.

Comment: Create an array instead, don't use multiple variables..

Comment: Why don't you have `string[] prints` (or other [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx))? Then you can do `prints[number]` to get the expected value without worrying about "print1", "print2", .. "printN" variables.

Comment: @user2864740 That is quite a simple yet genius idea. I can't believe I didn't think of that. That will make it a lot easier to get the correct value.

Comment: @zerkms I agree, it does look like a terrible design decision. Mainly because it _is_. This is just a way to let the 'operator' know how long it took between each click. The data also gets added to a text file so that the 'operator' can view it later. This was just a requested nice-to-have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an array of values:

```
public string[] prints;
```

You'll, of course, have to initialize it with the number of values you want to hold:

```
prints = new string[5]; // Holds five strings
```

Then, you can loop through them as such:

```
foreach (var number in prints) // Loop through each string in prints
{
    string printNumber = String.Format("print{0}", number);
}
```

If you want to be able to dynamically *add or remove* strings for `prints`, you should probably use a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]`

Comment: Aah. Code to support what @user2864740 said. This is exactly the approach I was after. You get the accepted answer since you actually wrote it as an answer.

Comment: I think my comment was technically first too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
PropertyInfo pi = this.GetType().GetProperty(printNumber);
string value = (string)(pi.GetValue(null, null));
```

Only thing you must do is to declare your variables as properties.

Source: http://www.karpach.com/Reflection-Property-Value.htm

-- EDIT --

I found a method I didn't know about... GetField which can return field values so that you don't need to declare your variables as properties, you can use them directly.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int a0 = 1;
    public int a1 = 2;
    public int a2 = 3;

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        int result = 1;

        for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
        {
            string fieldName = "a" + index;

            var field = typeof(SomeClass).GetField(fieldName);
            int fieldValue = (int)field.GetValue(this);

            result *= fieldValue;
        }

        Debug.Assert(result == 6);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution .. but for a different problem.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants to do.  They want to build the name of a variable within a string, then get the value of that variable.  To my knowledge this is impossible..

Comment: @MikeChristensen sure it's possible

Comment: And another thing. I tend to answer people's question, not help them (hence Q&A). Another thing is if he/she asked for advice, then I'd told them that that is not the best way to do things. You don't know what's the real problem behind the question, maybe he/she wants to build some scripting engine or whatnot.

Comment: @MikeChristensen `public string print1;` is a field, not a variable. I'm not a psychic.

Comment: @MikeChristensen and sure, that's possible too. It just requires more code :) MethodInfo.GetMethodBody() has LocalVariables property where you can retrieve values of local variables and using some magic, you can even retrieve names for those: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166767/retrieve-local-variable-name-from-pdb-files

Comment: That question pertains to a PDB file, basically a database of debug info.  Local variable names are gonna be optimized out of the IL though..  The compiler has no use for them.  But ok, I'll concede it is *technically* possible in certain cases if it makes you happy :)

Comment: @MikeChristensen yeah I'm aware of that, It's just not right to say something is impossible because you assume he doesn't have access to *.pdb or that he uses variables instead of fields where you can't be sure really.

Comment: Thank you both of you for your insight. I had a variable called print1. I also had a variable called printNumber, which was the string "print" + a number in a foreach loop. I wanted to take the printNumber combination and send that to a MessageBox. 
for instance: the first number is '1' so the printNumber variable would == 'print1'
I then wanted to print the value associated with the original print1 string, but I was instead getting the string "print1".
I hope that cleared up what I was asking for. :)